# How can I run a method after n minutes I received a geofence event in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, cllocationmanager

I'm working on a Geofence based iOS application and I would to know when the user stays more than 5 minutes inside a place.
Now, the geofence part is already done and working, I get the "enter" and "exit" events, but I want to execute some methods 5 minutes after I entered in a geofenced area, if I don't left it.

The main problem here is that NSTimers will not work with the app closed and I don't know how to focus this.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time!

P.S: CLVisit class is not valid on this case because the events for this class are not "in real time" and we cannot set a time-inside.

Comment: Try set up a notification?

Comment: I'm trying to do it without using a backend task. Because thinking in a future if a lot of people uses it it has no sense to be scheduling a lot of notifications to know this. But I keep it in mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSTimer when your app is Active like this :

```
 let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.printStr), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

and also if your app did receive `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` event you can save the current date to e.g `userDefaults` and use it after the user run the application again. Another way is to use `UILocalNotification` after you receive `AppWillTerminate` event, you should schedule the `UILocalNotificaiton` and trigger it after 5 minutes.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Yes, the problem here is that I want only to "track" when user stays >= 5 minutes. I don't want to show a local notification and as I know, there're no local silent notifications.